# Force push after hook in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-hook

Id like to know if it is possible to force a push after a hook in Mercurial.

I developed some pretag hooks to work with Redmine versions, and I close the version in the tracker if all the checks are OK. The thing is that the user can close the version but then not push the tag to the server. That's why I am in need of a way to make it happen.

I tried with "hg update" at the end of the pretag hook, but it wont work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- I think, you can use `pre-tag` hook, not rather special `pretag`
- If you want push, push from local to remote, not update local working dir: `hg tag NAME --config hooks.pre-tag='...; hg push'`